# Create Child record if does not exist and update

Tags: apex

I am trying to determine if the lookup field `Book__c` (a child record) exists on a `Project__c` object (parent record).  If it doesn't I would like to create and then update the values on the new child record from values on Parent.

```
    public static void createPrice(Id newProj2) {
        List<Book__c> bookList = new List<Book__c>();
        bookList.add(new Book__c(Project__c = newProj2));
    }

    public static void updateBook(list<Project__c> newpj) {
        list<Book_c> newpbe = new List<Book_c>();
        for (Project__c pj : newpj) {
             if (pj.Book__r == null && pj.Zoning__c == 'Test') {
                createSubPriceBook(pj.id);
    }
```

It never makes it to the `createSubPriceBook()` method.  In the debug I see the `pj.Book__r` is not equal to `null`.

Instead, I see this: `pj.Book__r : ()`
Is that blank?

The second thing is can I query the master and child record like this after the child record is created?

`pjrectest = [SELECT Id,(Select Booktest, Project__c from Book__c) from Project__c];`
I need to update a couple of fields on the newly created Book record.
Does the query need to be in a separate method?

P

Answer (score 0):

Your first question—

> Instead I see this: `pj.Book__r : ()` Is that blank?

A1: Yes, it's blank. Always use `field.isEmpty()` for list like:
`if(!pj.Book__r.isEmpty())`

Your second question:

A2: Yes you can query but after inserting/updating. Use `insert Book;` otherwise, the record will not be found as it is still not committed to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   Trying to picture what the second question will look like.  

'createSubPriceBook(pj.id);
            }
pjrectest = [SELECT Id,admin__c(Select Booktest, Project__c,zone__c from Book__c) from Project__c];

 if (pjrec.size() > 0) {
                for (Book__c pbe : pj.Book__r)  
{pbe.zone__c =pjrecc;


bit confused on assignment.  
Or would it be pjrec.Book__r.zone__c=pjrec__c

Comment: if (!pj.Book__r.isEmpty() && pj.Zoning_Type__c == 'Test') still appears not to be working.  
Confirmed both values and if I remove the pj.Boo__r from the criteria continued to the 'createPrice' method.   Any ideas why the  Book__r condition is not working?

Comment: Then we need your whole code. Pretty sure, order of execution or events should be the issue.